# do blanched, slivered almonds need a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

I have seen blanched, slivered almonds sold in packages. Hypothetically do these need a hechsher? I am aware that blanching involves heating so I imagine there could be kashrut concerns, but on the other hand [this tweet from the CRC](https://twitter.com/crckosher/status/35080579590537216) states that slivered almonds do not need a hechsher.

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like any alteration of a natural product requires a hechsher. I know that there are leniencies regarding using a cold knife such as cut up produce. But heating poses a lot more problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to another tweet from the cRc, blanched almonds require certification.](//twitter.com/crckosher/status/22898751309)

Answer (score 0):

According to the OU [here](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/ou-kosher-answers-your-top-ten-pesach-faqs/), no hechsher is required for Pesah.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!